# AWS Route53 random A-record

Tags: amazon-web-services, random, dns, a-records

Currently, I'm trying to output a random DNS A-record.
Unfortunately, I cannot seem to get it to work.

What I'm trying it the following:
I have a list of multiple IPv4 addresses. Once a DNS lookup will be made to play.domain.com, I need to output a random A record.

And then, just one, not the entire list of records.

How do I do this?

Any help will be very appreciated!

Comment: don't - it's the client's job to pick out an IP address from the set returned by the server.

Comment: What is your use case to return different IPv4 address in a round robin fashion. Also what is the TTL you are to set on your DNS entry

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [Weighted Routing](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html#routing-policy-weighted) in your Route 53 Hosted Zone.

When using weighted routing, you create multiple record sets with the same DNS name `play.domain.com`. Each record set will have a unique IP address. If each IP has an equal chance of being returned, then you want to give them all equal weights.

More information: [Values for Weighted Resource Record Sets](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-values-weighted.html)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've tried that but it returned an error: "Tried to create resource record set [name='play.domain.com', type='A', set-identifier='balancer'] but it already exists"

Comment: Make sure that (a) you're creating a "Weighted" record set and not a "Simple" one, and (b) that the set identifier is unique amongst your `play.domain.com` record sets.